# Is the preference relation represented by $u(x)=min(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ convex? True or False

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory

Taking two bundles $x$ and $y$,
$x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and  $y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$,
I understand I have to consider three cases to prove convexity, when $x\sim y$, $x\succ y$, $y\succ x$.
I understand when $x\sim y$, but I don't know how to prove the convex combination for the last two cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^3$ be consumption bundles such that $y \geq x, z \geq x$. Let $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

\begin{equation}
    u(\lambda y + (1-\lambda) z) = \min(\lambda (y_1,y_2,y_3) + (1 - \lambda) (z_1,z_2,z_3))
\end{equation}

Using the inequality "the minimum of a sum $\geq$ the sum of the minimums"

\begin{equation}
    u(\lambda y + (1-\lambda) z) \geq \min(\lambda (y_1,y_2,y_3)) + \min( (1 - \lambda) (z_1,z_2,z_3) )
\end{equation}

Since $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we have $\lambda \geq 0, 1 - \lambda \geq 0$, we can factor each of them out of each min.

\begin{equation}
    u(\lambda y + (1-\lambda) z) \geq \lambda \min(y_1,y_2,y_3) + (1-\lambda) \min(z_1,z_2,z_3)
\end{equation}

Recalling the definition of the function $u$

\begin{equation}
    u(\lambda y + (1-\lambda) z) \geq \lambda u(y) + (1-\lambda) u(z)
\end{equation}

Since $y \geq x, z \geq x$, we have that $u(y) \geq u(x), u(z) \geq u(x)$. Therefore,

\begin{equation}
u(\lambda y + (1-\lambda) z) \geq \lambda u(x) + (1-\lambda) u(x) = u(x) 
\end{equation}

From here we get $\lambda y + (1-\lambda) z \geq x$.

Therefore, we conclude that the preference relation represented by $u$ is convex.

Answer: True

Comment: I guess the problem asks for the convexity of the represented preferences.

Comment: Isn't the same u(x)=min(x,y) convex in 2D? Shouldn't that extend to 3D also?

Comment: I tweaked it a bit to match the new question (OP edited it). Someone just decided to give me a -1.

Comment: @ Nicolas Torres  You, while editing your post, forgot to delete the sentence 'It is actually false' at the beginning'.

Comment: @BakerStreet Done, thanks

Comment: what is x here? is it just another bundle? how is it comparable to the convex combination?

Comment: @reindeer x is another bundle, which is defined to be weakly worse than both y and z. To prove that the preference relation is convex, I prove the convex combination of y and z is also weakly preferred to x. I know there are more equivalent definitions of convexity for preference relations, but this is the one I used here.

Comment: @NicolasTorres Thanks!!